# Is this movement possible?

Tags: kinematics, rotational-kinematics

My friend and I were arguing over some random facebook shared video. On this video, one guy throws up a rotating stick then, while it rotates on air, he kicks through it. Is it even possible? Or is it an edited footage?

https://www.facebook.com/video.php?v=10153026007912287 (sorry, the link is from facebook,I don't know you can see it or not)

Comment: This probably could be possible, if the guy is trained enough to kick through the gap present in the minimum amount of time. I see no problem here.

Comment: Notice also that he catches and stops the stick during the kick. So the stick's rotation is significantly slowed for the last part of the kick, making it easier to retract the leg without being hit.

Comment: What I mostly wonder is, lets say x amount of force required for make floating iron stick on air for few sec. That x amount of force can make y per second rotation. So if even human can throw make that high x amount of force, it must be quite fast (high y rotation) for kick through it (damn i can't explain perfeclty, english isn't my language).

Comment: The rotation of the stick and the hang-time of the stick are completely unrelated. He can spin it as fast or slow as he wants.

Answer (score 1):

First he spins the stick and then he lets it rotate in air. If you watch carefully, you can see that he stops it with his left hand before kicking and then walks away: **he didn't kick it during rotation!**.